How to get UTM params stored in local storage to send them in the response after payment?
I have an issue with UTM parameters that are stored in local Storage but I can't send them in my response when someone going checkout --- payment --- thank you page.
Do you have any idea how I can implement that? Some solution that you made in Next JS?
Got the UTMs in local storage, bought something from my page, going checkout, payment, and on thank you page in Network tab, I get my response without Tags. I added tags with all UTM parameters in it, added in the interface, in fetch in the body, but still missing something.
